# How to select all classes started with Yellow

Tags: css

```
<span class="yellowTiger">&nbsp;</span>
<a class="yellowIceTiger">&nbsp;</a>
<div class="yellowCow">&nbsp;</div>
<b class="yellowApe">&nbsp;</b>
<c class="yellowIce">&nbsp;</c>
```

How to selected alll the classes started with yellow or have ice ?
I know it's possible don't remember..

**Edit::**
Why not separted classes, because i don't like :p

Comment: Why not have class `yellow tiger` or `yellow ape` instead?

Comment: Thanks but not answer my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `starts with` css selector `^=`, than select class as attribute:

```css
[class^="yellow"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
[class^="blue"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
[class^="red"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="yellowTiger">&nbsp;</span>
<a class="yellowIceTiger">&nbsp;</a>
<div class="yellowCow">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bluewCow">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="redwCow">&nbsp;</div>
<b class="yellowApe">&nbsp;</b>
<c class="yellowIce">&nbsp;</c>
```

But (correct me if i'm wrong) it's slower than just selecting `.yellow` when you have separate classes as groups `yellow ice tiger`

Comment: What would be a reason to use this over making 2 different classes?

Comment: @Fabiotocchi lazyness to use best practices. But since OP said two classes is not good for him, than it's the answer.

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs `$class = preg_replace('/[^a-z ]/i', '', implode(' ', $arrayOfAttributes));` - not so long script to allow only letters and whitespaces in class string... Rethink your code better.

Comment: Lol, why everybody is trying to talk me over :p

Comment: @Justinas Yes i know this is what OP asked for, i was just wondering why someone would prefer this kind of approach. Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

In html elements, when a space is given between 2 words in the class attribute, the element is considered to be belonging to both classes. So restructure you classes like this...

```
<span class="yellow tiger">&nbsp;</span> 
<a class="yellow ice tiger">&nbsp;</a>
<div class="yellow cow">&nbsp;</div>
<b class="yellow ape">&nbsp;</b>
<c class="yellow ice">&nbsp;</c>
```

The first `<span>` element belongs to **both** classes, `yellow` and `tiger`.
Similarly, the `<a>` element belongs to **all three** classes, `yellow`, `ice` and `tiger`

Now use `.yellow` selector to select all elements of class `yellow`. Since all the elements in this example have the class `yellow`, all of them will be selected.

```
.yellow {
    / *Whatever styling you want */
}
```

---

Another example just to make it clear:

To select all elements of class `ice`, ie `<a>` and `<c>` in this case, use `.ice`.

```
.ice { /* This selects the <a> and <c> elements */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Justinas said, a solution would be create a class "Yellow" and a class "ice".
Then you could create something like this.

```
<span class="yellow Tiger">&nbsp;</span>
<a class="yellow Ice Tiger">&nbsp;</a>
<div class="yellow Cow">&nbsp;</div>
<b class="yellow Ape">&nbsp;</b>
<c class="yellow Ice">&nbsp;</c>
```

This way you can assign the ice style to elements who have ice and the yellow style to those who have yellow as a class